# Xamarin Prism Android won't lose TabbedPage or change NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, prism

We have a project using a `NavigationPage` and `TabbedPage` working as expected in iOS but not Android (Xamarin Forms (2.3.3.193) with Prism (6.3.0)).

I've set up a [sample project available here](https://github.com/pmccolgan/PrismNavigationSOSample).

This application consists of three pages which are nested in a `NavigationPage` and a `TabbedPage` (APage, BPage and CPage) and a fourth page which should lose the `TabbedPage` and keep a `NavigationPage` (B1Page is available through BPage).

`NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/LayoutTabbedPage/APage");`

[Opening APage with navigation and tab bar on iOS](https://github.com/pmccolgan/PrismNavigationSOSample/blob/master/images/ios_apage.png) and [looks fine on Android](https://github.com/pmccolgan/PrismNavigationSOSample/blob/master/images/android_apage.png)

[BPage has an 'Add' button on the navigation bar](https://github.com/pmccolgan/PrismNavigationSOSample/blob/master/images/ios_bpage.png) which also [looks fine on Android](https://github.com/pmccolgan/PrismNavigationSOSample/blob/master/images/android_bpage.png)

Clicking 'Add' should open [B1Page](https://github.com/pmccolgan/PrismNavigationSOSample/blob/master/images/ios_b1page.png).  This still has the navigation bar (with a 'Save' button instead of 'Add') but no tab bar.

`m_navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/LayoutTabbedPage/BPage/B1Page");`

But on [Android B1Page](https://github.com/pmccolgan/PrismNavigationSOSample/blob/master/images/android_b1page.png) the tab bar remains and as does the original navigation bar (with the Add button instead of Save).

Is there something wrong I'm doing with navigation which makes these inconsistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have issues with your navigation.  First off, if you want to navigate within a TabbedPage and keep your tabs, you need to wrap your Tab in a NavigationPage, not the TabbedPage in a NavigationPage.  Something like this:

`<NavigationPage Title="B">
    <x:Arguments>
    <local:BPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>`

This will allow yo to navigate within the actual Tab.

If this is not what you want to do, then keep your tabbedPage wrapped in a navigation page and then when you navigate to B1Page force an async nav call using 'NavigateAsync("B1Page", usemodalNavigation: false)`. This will bounce you out of the tabbed page but keep you within the navigation page with the back arrow and toolbar item.

Secondly, your navigation Uri's are a mess.  Navigation in Prism is relative to where you are calling it.

When you make this call `m_navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/LayoutTabbedPage/BPage/B1Page");` you are pushing all those pages onto the navigation stack again.  If you hit your back button on Android you will see what I mean.

All you have to do is from BPageViewModel call NavigateAsync("B1Page");.

That should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I don't want to navigate within the tab, so correcting the navigation to be relative and use the 'usemodalnavigation' parameter were exactly what I needed.  Thank you, and thanks for all your work on Prism!