# Xamarin Prism - Navigating from a Tab page to a new page does not open/push the new page

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Recently I implemented a `TabbedPage` into my `Xamarin.Forms` application. However, this introduced some navigation problems with `Prism`. I think it should be something obvious but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

I am using a `TabbedPage` as my starting page, this contains several tabs. The starting tab, `HomePage` contains a list and on click of these list items it will navigate to another page, which should open as a new page (so covering the entire tab page). Before implementing the `TabbedPage` this worked fine, but now the page is not being opened, while it's `ViewModel` and backend page code is being loaded / initialized just fine, but the page itself (`XAML`) just wont display.

I got a feeling that it IS being opened but for same reason it is sitting behind the `TabbedPage`.

After reading up several posts, (one of them being this: [Xamarin Prism Android won't lose TabbedPage or change NavigationPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098943/xamarin-prism-android-wont-lose-tabbedpage-or-change-navigationpage)), I already tried the following  without any effect:

1. Setting `useModalNavigation: false` in my `NavigateAsync` method
2. Changing the route to `MyTabbedPage/MYChildTabPage/TheGoToPage`
3. Trying to remove the tab child page out of the `NavigationPage` XAML

**The TabbedPage:**

```
<TabbedPage
    x:Class="PCS2.APP.RootTabbedPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PCS2.APP"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
    android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
    BarBackgroundColor="#F5F5F5"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
    SelectedTabColor="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"
    SelectedTabIndex="{Binding SelectedTab}"
    UnselectedTabColor="#979797">

    <TabbedPage.Children>

        <NavigationPage Title="Mijn Taken">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:HomePage />
            </x:Arguments>
            <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
                <FontImageSource
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource IconsFontFamily}"
                    Glyph="{x:Static local:FontawesomeSolidFont.Tasks}"
                    Size="25" />
            </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        </NavigationPage>
        
        <NavigationPage Title="DKS">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:DKSPage />
            </x:Arguments>
            <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
                <FontImageSource
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource IconsFontFamily}"
                    Glyph="{x:Static local:FontawesomeSolidFont.CalendarCheck}"
                    Size="25" />
            </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        </NavigationPage>
        
        <!-- few other tabs left out for readability --> 

    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

**TabbedPage ViewModel (nothing special):**

```
public class RootTabbedViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;


    public RootTabbedViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

}
```

** `ViewModelBase` has the following implementations: `BindableBase, IInitialize, IInitializeAsync, INavigationAware, IDestructible`

**The tab child page ViewModel (HomePage):**

```
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private bool _showShimmer;

    public HomeViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
       : base(navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public override async Task InitializeAsync(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        try
        {
           // Loading data logic (which works), omitted for readability

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowShimmer = false;
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            ShowShimmer = false;
        }
    }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
       // Some logic when navigating back to this page
    }


    private async Task LocationSelected(Projects location)
    {
        var parameters = new NavigationParameters
        {
            { "clientId", location.ClientId },
            { "projectId", location.ProjectId }
        };

        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("LocationPage", parameters, useModalNavigation: false, false);
    }

}
```

** The LocationSelected event is triggered and when it hits the NavigateAsync I can see that the proper ViewModel of the LocationPage is being intialized.

**LocationPage ViewModel:**

```
public class LocationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public LocationViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
       : base(navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }


    public override async Task InitializeAsync(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            // Initialize data logic - omitted for readability
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            
        }
    }

}
```

The `InitializeAsync` of the `LocationViewModel` is being hit and executed without errors, but after compeltion the XAML is simple not pushed on top (the page is not visible). Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Have you checked the status of `INavigationResult` returned from the `NavigateAsync` method to see if no exceptions occurred during navigation?

Comment: @MateusHenrique good call, I  checked the result and when not using the tabitem in a `NavigationPage` I get the error `PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage` which is kind of obvious, so I added my tabitem (page) back into a `NavigationPage`, then I get no errors but the navigation does not happen. Though, when I remove my other `NavigationPage` tabs, the one remaining tabitem DOES work.. Furthermore, when using a single `NavigationPage` the navigation works but the tabbar remains visible, while I want to move out of the tabpage instead.

Comment: I don't know which version of Prism you're using, but in the latest released version (8.0.0.1909)
 navigating via TabbedPages is broken. Can you check if this is your case? [Navigating via TabbedPages is broken in the latest Prism released version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66754710/12685302).

Comment: I am using the same (latest) Prism version 8.0.0.19, however I am using it with `Prism.Unity.Forms` instead of `Prism.DryIoc`. But it seems like it is (sort of) the same issue. I'll try to add it to the BUG post with a related repo. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: `Prism.DryIoc` is just the container, the issue is in `Prism.Forms` library.

Comment: Ok after I created a small repo and did some more testing on my original project I found out that it is 100% the same issue. One additional question though with which I am struggling as well, say it all works as it is supposed to, how do I push the page that is being navigated to as a entire new page, without showing the tabbar? Is my above code the right way to do it, since when I am using just 1 tabpage it does not hide the tabbar on navigation.. Or should I then just navigate as a modal to accomplish this?

Comment: There are a few ways to achieve this behavior, but it should be asked as a completely new standalone question because it is easier to answer and can help other developers.